# Best way to setup a high performance LAN with a tethered laptop for internet?

Tags: networking, routing

This question should be fairly easy for all you network guys out there.

So, here is the rundown of what I have access to: -Linksys EA6500 high performance router w/ 4 Ethernet ports + 1 for internet.

-10/100 Ethernet switch

-cat5/cat5e Ethernet cables (some cat6)

-modem if that's needed?

-Laptop running windows 7 with access to the internet over WiFi (only laptop that can have the password to the WiFi. Don't ask why, it's school policy and there are no exceptions to be made here. The people running this are strict, and this is not a place for people to tell me how to convince them)

Now, here is what I need: -LAN that has very high b/w with very low latency for local remote desktop-like sessions. There's going to be between 3-6 devices on this LAN at any given time.

-Laptop needs to be tethered via ethernet to the router or switch to provide internet for all connected devices to the LAN via the laptop's WiFi adapter

Can someone describe to me what I would need and what I would need to do to set this up? Perhaps describe the setup that I would do to achieve this? Feel free to add any equipment that I would need access to. And, no this is not homework.

Comment: In network and sharing center, hit adapter settings.  Select the ethernet port, right click, properties, sharing, allow other network users blah blah.  Check that box, and select the wifi connection in the drop down.

Comment: as for the hardware, just plug all the devices you want to have on the lan into the switch (including the laptop with wifi) and let them configure themselves.  No modem required, use the cat 6 on the laptop to switch connection to minimize latency.

Comment: Cat 6 isn't going to help much if all you have is a 10/100 switch.  I'd recommend plugging into the 10/100/1000 ports on the EA6500 or get a dedicated 10/100/1000 switch if you want high performance on the LAN.